# Django Url not matching?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to match the following dynamic url in django :

```
http://localhost:8000/gif/1/this-is-tests
```

am trying following code :

```
^gif/(?P<image_id>\w{0,50})/(?P<image_title>\w{0,500})/$
```

it is error:

> Page not found (404)
>   Request Method: GET
>   Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/gif/1/this-is-tests

what am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expression `\w` doesn't include `-` sign. You need to add it:

```
^gif/(?P<image_id>\w{0,50})/(?P<image_title>[-\w]{0,500})/$
```